# How to test an endpoint in go?

Tags: go

I wrote a small test function in go. I'm having hard time in making a request to actual endpoint and test it. I tried importing the file which has the handler function (I think I'm trying to import whole directory : `import (".")`). Both my project.go and handler_test.go are in the same directory (I don't think this matters). Could someone give me heads up so that I can write more tests.
Here is my project.go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"

)

type Person struct {
    ID        string   `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Firstname string   `json:"firstname,omitempty"`
    Lastname  string   `json:"lastname,omitempty"`
    Address   *Address `json:"address,omitempty"`
}

type Address struct {
    City  string `json:"city,omitempty"`
    State string `json:"state,omitempty"`
}

var people []Person;

func GetPersonEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(req)
    for _, item := range people {
        if item.ID == params["id"] {
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(item)
            return
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&Person{})
}


func GetPeopleEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
 json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(people)
}

func CreatePersonEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(req)
    var person Person
    _ = json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&person)
    person.ID = params["id"]
    people = append(people, person)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(people)
}

func DeletePersonEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(req)
    for index, item := range people {
        if item.ID == params["id"] {
            people = append(people[:index], people[index+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(people)
}

func main() {
    Router := mux.NewRouter()
    people = append(people, Person{ID: "1", Firstname: "sarath", Lastname: "v", Address: &Address{City: "sunnyvale", State: "CA"}})
    people = append(people, Person{ID: "2", Firstname: "dead", Lastname: "pool"})

    // router.PathPrefix("/tmpfiles/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))

    Router.HandleFunc("/people", GetPeopleEndpoint).Methods("GET")
    Router.HandleFunc("/people/{id}", GetPersonEndpoint).Methods("GET")
    Router.HandleFunc("/people/{id}", CreatePersonEndpoint).Methods("POST")

   c := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
})

// Insert the middleware
   handler := c.Handler(Router)
   http.ListenAndServe(":12345", handler)

}
```

Here is my handler_test.go. In this code I'm testing GetPersonEndPoint.

```
package main

import (
  "."
  "net/http"
  "net/http/httptest"
  "testing"
  "encoding/json"
)

func checkResponseCode(t *testing.T, expected, actual int) {
    if expected != actual {
        t.Errorf("Expected response code %d. Got %d\n", expected, actual)
    }
}

func executeRequest(req *http.Request) *httptest.ResponseRecorder {
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
     handler := http.HandlerFunc(GetPersonEndpoint)
     handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
     if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
       fmt.Printf("Handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v" , status, http.statusOk);
      }
    return rr
}

func TestGetPersonEndPoint(t *testing.T){
  req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/people/5", nil)
  response := executeRequest(req)
  checkResponseCode(t, http.StatusNotFound, response.Code)
   var m map[string]string
   json.Unmarshal(response.Body.Bytes(), &m)
  if m["error"] != "Product not found" {
        t.Errorf("Expected the 'error' key of the response to be set to 'Product not found'. Got '%s'", m["error"])
    }
}
```

And finally this is the error:

```
./new.go:14: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./myproject.go:62
./new.go:20: not enough arguments in call to server.ListenAndServeTLS
    have ()
    want (string, string)
```

Comment: You don't import your code to test, the tests exist in the same package. If you do need to import a package for black-box testing, always use the full import path, never the relative path (but you can't ever import a main package).

Comment: The error says it all: you have two functions both called `main` in the same package, one in `new.go` line 14, one in `myproject.go` line 62. You can't have two functions of the same name in the same package (except for the special case of `init` functions). You also have an invalid call to `ListenAndServeTLS` which passes no arguments when that function requires two arguments, both strings.

Comment: @Adrian I was not watching other files. I have a flat directory which caused the problem. There is a file new.go in my directory which has the second main(). I corrected it. How should I import the specific handler (I'm doing it this way: import ("project")) ?

Comment: If the files are in the same directory, you don't need to import them, just declare them in the same package. You might want to [read about packages in Go](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/11).

Comment: @SarathVelamuri: go packages are located by directory, with one non-test package per directory. You should be able to test and compile by their import path. You shouldn't be using `go run` and should not have to specify individual files on the command line.  Also see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for details.

Comment: @JimB I was using `go test` for my test code. But It could not locate the handler(GetPersonEndpoint) which I've created in the endpoints file. The test is giving me `./handler_test.go:19: undefined: GetPersonEndpoint`. But there is clearly a handler for this in the main.go.

Comment: @SarathVelamuri: you couldn't have been testing the package, because you have invalid Go files. If you're still not sure what we mean, please show the exact commands you're using.

Comment: @JimB go run project.go and go test handlers_test.go

Comment: @SarathVelamuri: yes, like I said, you should not have to specify individual files on the command line. You should be specifying your package, or using the package implied by the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at some http tests I've written: https://github.com/eamonnmcevoy/go_web_server/blob/master/pkg/server/user_router_test.go

```
    // Arrange
    us := mock.UserService{}
    testUserRouter := NewUserRouter(&us, mux.NewRouter())
...
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT", "/", payload)
    r.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    testUserRouter.ServeHTTP(w, r)
```

Simply create an instance of your router and call the endpoints using go's `httptest`. This snippet will perform a `PUT` request at the default endpoint `/`

Comment: How do I install the pkg go_rest_api/pkg?

Comment: @SarathVelamuri You don't, that's just the name of my project. You just need to create an instance of the struct containing your routes and serve it with `httptest` and a request. In my case `testUserRouter` is a (poorlyNamed?) instance of my `UserRouter` struct, I invoke a `PUT` request on the path `"/"`